# Time-based rotation

Tags: java, animation, 3d, mouse, jogl

I have a 3D cube that I'm trying to rotate smoothly along the Y-axis. As of now, when I click my mouse button, the cube rotates to the new value instantly (like Tetris), but would like to show it gradually rotate to the new rotational value over a specific. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
// Within Shp_Cube class
public float cubeRotY = 1.0f; // rotate on Y-axis
public static float cubeAngle = .01f; // angle of rotation
public static float cubeSpeed = 1.0f; // speed of rotation
...

// Within drawCube() method (called in JOGL's display(GLAutoDrawable...) )
gl.glRotatef(cubeAngle, 0, cubeRotY, 0); // rotation of cube
...

// Within MouseInput class
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) 
{
    switch(m.getButton())
    {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Left Mouse Button Clicked");

        if(Shp_Cube.cubeAngle < Shp_Cube.cubeAngle + 90f)
        {
            Shp_Cube.cubeAngle += Shp_Cube.cubeSpeed;
        }

        break;
    case ...
```

The desired effect that I've been trying to achieve is when the user clicks the left mouse button, the cube will begin to rotate and continue rotating until it's angle reaches a certain value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating the cube in the `mouseClicked()` method but it should be updated within
the `display()` method:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    updateCube();
    drawCube(...);
}

private void updateCube() {
    if(Shp_Cube.cubeAngle < Shp_Cube.cubeAngle + 90f) {
        Shp_Cube.cubeAngle += Shp_Cube.cubeSpeed;
    } else {
        Shp_Cube.cubeSpeed = 0; // stop rotattion after angle reched
    }
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
    switch(m.getButton()) {
    case 1:
        Shp_Cube.cubeSpeed = INITIAL_SPEED; // this should only start rotation by setting positive speed
        break;
    }
}
```

To have a smooth rendering with constant framerate, append the following to the main() method:

```
Animator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 60);
animator.add(canvas);
animator.start();
```

For more see code at the end of [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-3).

Comment: It works beautifully, but I see a new problem with the code. It rotates pass 90 degrees, because Shp_Cube.cubeAngle is constantly updating the value. The problem is within the if statement. It looks like I might have to use a for-loop instead to check every 90th degree. Thanks for the kind help! :)